# Spring Roo and web scaffolding issue

Tags: aspectj, spring-roo, scaffolding, jspx

I am using Spring Roo.  I removed the Spring Roo web scaffolding annotation from my controller and deleted all the related JSPX files.  Now I am the following error:

Method 'org.springframework.roo.classpath.details.MethodMetadataBuilder@d9c877' failed to provide a body, despite being identified for ITD inclusion

Can someone help me to troubleshoot it?  Thanks!

Comment: If you don't get any help here, I'd recommend heading to the Spring Roo forums: http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?f=67

Answer (score 0):

We're running into the same problem, and have found this:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=346913

But we haven't found the source of the issue.

UPDATE:

As edit mentions, re-run

controller all --package ~.web

and roo seems to fix itself.

LAST UPDATE:

So the reason this fixed itself was in the ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean, roo is expecting to find at least one @RooWebScaffold annotation in the Controllers, and if they are all gone, it isn't happy.  To fix our problem, we moved all of the methods from the AspectJ file into the java file and eliminated the roo management of this bean too.  Things seem to be happy again, at least for now.

Comment: So I got to a clean point, and re-ran: <code>controller all --package ~.web</code> and roo seemed to fix itself and became a lot happier.  Not 100% on the why, but that does seem to fix this problem.